# Can we delete a record from a table which related with other tables using one to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have created a database and created 10 tables. The master table have Id column common in all the other tables. I have connected these tables with one to many relationship and vice versa. Now I need to delete a single record from the master table by giving the ID. Does it automatically delete the records in other tables or I have to specify functions for deleting the records in other tables associated with the ID.Please clarify.All these process are done using Java hibernate concept. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it automatically delete the records in other tables

It depends on how you've specified the foreign keys to MySQL. You get several choices. Which one did you make? If you made the choice that allows deletions, it deletes. If you made the choice that prevents it, the deletion doesn't happen at all, not even from the master.